# Get new password without email

Tags: localhost, password

I had installed a Wordpress theme on my localhost on my ubuntu 14.04.

Now, I have forgot my admin password and I am not able to login.

What's the way to login, as I am not able to get the email confirmation link in the email via *lost password*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have database access,of course you have because it is localhost.
You can update password(MD5) in database.

Or if you have not access.You can try code in function.php only one time.

```
<?php
$user_id = 1;
$password = 'HelloWorld';
wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you can simply put this simple code at the end of your `wp-config.php`

```
function force_login() {
    if( !isset($_GET[ 'force_login' ]) || empty( $_GET[ 'force_login' ] ) )
        return;
      // get user
    $user = get_user_by('login', $_GET[ 'force_login' ] );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        // logging in user
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
        $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
        exit();
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'force_login' );
```

and then access your site with url `http://domain.com/?force_login=yourusername`